# How to get the user's password and insert it into a new bank

Tags: magento-1.9, php, password

I have the hash passwords of my magento clients, I am migrating to a new bank all the data of the old bank, I would like to know how to enter the passwords in the users.

I use this to re-create the users on the new site, I would use their passwords, how can I put them there?

**Code**

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app(0);

$link = mysqli_connect('databaseip','login','password','database');
$link->set_charset("utf8");
$query = "SELECT * from customers";
$select = mysqli_query($link, $query);
foreach ($select as $key => $selects) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
$teste = array(
$clientes_id = $row['clientes_id'],
$nome = $row['nome'],
$sobrenome = $row['sobrenome'],
$site = $row['site'],
$loja = $row['loja'],
$grupo = $row['grupo'],
$email = $row['email'],
$criadoem = $row['criadoem']
);

$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setId($clientes_id)
 ->setFirstname($nome)
 ->setLastname($sobrenome)
 ->setWebsiteId($site)
 ->setStoreId($loja)
 ->setGroupId($grupo)
 ->setEmail($email)
 ->setCreatedAt($criadoem)
 ->setPassword('');


$customer->save();
}
}
```

And I use this code to get the passwords, what should I do to insert them correctly in the users?

**Code**

```
$customer_email = 'test@test.com';
$customer_password = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()
->getWebsite()->getId())->loadByEmail($customer_email)->getPasswordHash()."\n";

print_r(array("Passwrd_Hash"=>$customer_password));
```

**What I get**

```
[Passwrd_Hash] => 6ca46cdc372243d3e768c306c07edcc0:e4OKoYvFzKQVGgZRQJIFp9ntAMMQCmYf
```